# Just text for DisplayName

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, metadata, html-helper

How can I just put the value of `DisplayName` attribute of model's property instead of using `Html.LabelFor()` in my view? `Html.LabelFor()` doesn't fir for me 'cause it getting me `<label for=""></label>` which corrupts my page's layout.
So here is sample of Model's property:

```
[DisplayName("House number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must specify house number")]
        [Range(1, 9999, ErrorMessage = "You have specify a wrong house number")]
        public UInt32? buildingNumber
        {
            get { return _d.buildingNumber; }
            set { _d.buildingNumber = value; }
        }
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch it from the metadata:

```
<%
    var displayName = ModelMetadata
        .FromLambdaExpression(x => x.buildingNumber, Html.ViewData)
        .DisplayName;
%>

<%= displayName %>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get the displayname from the metadata:

```
@ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.buildingNumber, ViewData).DisplayName
```

Edit:

I think you can still use the statement for MVC2, just change the @:

<%: ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.buildingNumber, ViewData).DisplayName %>

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin! Your answer is for MVC3 Razor view engine but I use MVC2, so I couldn't that.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing heavily from http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/03/asp-net-mvc-labelfor-helper-with-htmlattributes.aspx, I created an extension method to do this. It outputs with span tags which are always safe. You could also modify this to omit the span tag entirely (eliminating two overloads since you can never take attributes in that case).

Create a class with this content, make sure your pages are importing that class' namespace, then use this in the view like `Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)`

```
public static class DisplayNameForHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return DisplayNameFor(html, expression, new RouteValueDictionary());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DisplayNameFor(html, expression, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("span");
        tag.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        tag.SetInnerText(labelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));

    }
}
```

Comment: I did test this only in MVC3 because I don't have an MVC2 project handy at the moment, but I expect it could work without there too without much trouble.